# mv using filename expansion operation caused files to disappear

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files named

```
index.html.1
index.html.2
...
```

I tried to write a bash script to fix all of their extensions

```
for file in *.html.*
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.html.*}.jpg"
done
```

which made all of the files disappear.
What have I done?!

Comment: Your script will move both `index.html.1` and `index.html.2` to `index.jpg`. Is that what you intended? (One must be lost?) At any rate I don't see how "all of the files disappeared". There should be at least one left.

Comment: By the way, for your future mass renaming jobs, I suggest that you at least have a dry run by echo'ing your mv commands. Or better yet, use a dedicated tool (that let you preview the changes). For instance, I use a variant of Larry Wall's rename script in Perl. A good starter is here: http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/09/renaming-with-larry-wall/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have moved each `index.html` file, one at a time, to the same target filename. Unfortunately all but the last has now been overwritten.

```
touch index.html.{1,2,3,4,5}
for file in *.html.*; do echo mv "$file" "${file%.html.*}.jpg"; done
```

Output

```
mv index.html.1 index.jpg
mv index.html.2 index.jpg
mv index.html.3 index.jpg
mv index.html.4 index.jpg
mv index.html.5 index.jpg
```

Comment: But the OP said "all of the files disappeared", which seems impossible. There should be one left.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I took that to mean "all the _index.html_ files"

Comment: I didn't notice because I had an index.html that I had manually renamed index.jpg before running this. It's so obvious in retrospect...